# Writing a pytorch neural net class that has functions for both model fitting and prediction

Tags: python, pytorch

I want a PyTorch neural net to predict y using x where, for example,

x = torch.tensor([[6,2],[5,2],[1,3],[7,6]]).float() 
y = torch.tensor([1,5,2,5]).float()

For this, I have written the following PyTorch class which can fit y using x. But, I am not able to extend the code to predict using new values of x, x_test. Can somebody please guide me in this regard?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim import SGD


class MyNeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(2,4,bias=True)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(4,1,bias=True)
        self.loss = nn.MSELoss()

    def fit(self,x,y):
        def forward(self,x):
            x = self.layer1(x)
            x = self.layer2(x)

            return x.squeeze()

        
        def compile(self,x):
            forward(self,x)
            opt = SGD(self.parameters(),lr=0.01) # parameters from first forward pass
        
        
        compile(self,x)
        
        losses = []
        for _ in range(100):
            opt.zero_grad() # flush previous epoch's gradient
            res = forward(self,x)
            loss_value = self.loss(res,y)
            loss_value.backward() # compute gradient
            opt.step() # Perform iteration using gradient above
            losses.append(loss_value.item())
        y_train_hat = forward(self,x)
        return y_train_hat.detach().numpy()


    def predict(self,x_test):

         """
         
         need help in this part
         
         """

        # y_test_hat = forward(self,x_test)
        # return y_test_hat.detach().numpy()
```

I changed the code provided by Ivan. The following is the working version of the code:

```
class MyNeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(2, 4, bias=True)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(4, 1, bias=True)
        self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
        self.compile_()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x.squeeze()

    def fit(self, x, y):
     
        losses = []
        for epoch in range(100):
            
            ## Inference
            res = self(x)  #instead of self(self,x)
            loss_value = self.loss(res,y)

            ## Backpropagation
            self.opt.zero_grad()  # flush previous epoch's gradient; this should be the first step, I think
            loss_value.backward() # compute gradient
           
            self.opt.step()       # Perform iteration using gradient above

            ## Logging
            losses.append(loss_value.item())
        
    def compile_(self):
        self.opt = SGD(self.parameters(), lr=0.01)
       
    def predict(self,x_test):
        self.eval()
        y_test_hat = self(x_test) #instead of forward(self,x_test)
        return y_test_hat.detach().numpy()
        self.train()
```

```
x = torch.tensor([[6,2],[5,2],[1,3],[7,6]]).float()
y = torch.tensor([1,5,2,5]).float()

model = MyNeuralNet()
model.fit(x,y)
model.predict(x)
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal example with some modifications carried out to your code:

```
class MyNeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(2, 4, bias=True)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(4, 1, bias=True)
        self.loss = nn.MSELoss()
        self.compile_()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x.squeeze()

    def fit(self, x, y):
        losses = []
        for epoch in range(100):
            ## Inference
            res = self(self,x)
            loss_value = self.loss(res,y)

            ## Backpropagation
            loss_value.backward() # compute gradient
            self.opt.zero_grad()  # flush previous epoch's gradient
            self.opt.step()       # Perform iteration using gradient above

            ## Logging
            losses.append(loss_value.item())
        
    def compile_(self, x):
        self.opt = SGD(self.parameters(), lr=0.01)
       
    def predict(self, x_test):
        self.eval()
        y_test_hat = self(x_test)
        return y_test_hat.detach().numpy()
        self.train()
```

Which can be used like this for training:

```
>>> model = MyNeuralNet()
>>> model.fit(x, y) # fit on some data (x, y)
```

Then perform inference with some other data `x_test`:

```
>>> model.predict(x_test)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping. I have a small doubt regarding the line 'self.train()'. Why is it included in the prediction function?

Comment: Further, how do I get the training predictions...can I just do like model.predict(x_train) with your improvised code?

Comment: (a) the call to `self.train` simply ensures that the model is put back to training mode after the prediction step, which can be useful when alternating between training and validation steps. (b) Indeed, it should be `model.predict(x_test)` instead of `model(x_test)`, I have edited this line accordingly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification. I tried running the code. The following error was thrown: 
TypeError: compile_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: The error in compile() got solved by removing argument 'x' from compile definition. Now, another error pops up: TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: It should be `y_test_hat = self(x_test)`